# How can I characterize the type of solution vector that comes out of a matrix?

Tags: matrices, linear-algebra

`Ax = b`.  I need a way to analyze a square matrix `A` to see if its solution vector `x` will always be positive when `b` is positive.

This question arises from solving the radiosity equation:

http://www.siggraph.org/education/materials/HyperGraph/radiosity/images/slide11.jpg (noob alert)

I'm interested to know when A is *incorrect*, which would be when `x` has negative values even though `b` is positive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If and only if all the entries of $A^{-1}$ are non-negative.

**Proof:** If $(A^{-1})_{ij}$ is negative, and $b$ is $1$ in the $j$-th coordinate and very small in every other, then $A^{-1} b$ is negative in the $i$-th component.

On the other hand, if every entry of $A^{-1}$ is non-negative, then clearly $b$ positive implies $A^{-1} b$ positive.

Comment: You are fast David, I was just in the middle of posting.  

Comment: A wide class of matrices having nonnegative inverses is that of M-matrices. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-matrix . The matrix in the link you posted has the right sign-pattern (i.e., it is a Z-matrix), so you just need to check that the spectral radius of the matrix $\rho_i F_{ij}$ is less than 1 to make sure that your matrix is an M-matrix.

Comment: @David, thank you.  @Federico:  Thank you for that insightful comment. 